# [Bootstrap]"Responsive" iframes are either cropped or too big

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, iframe, responsive-design

i have a thumbnail gallery made of images like this:

```html
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 thumb">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#" id="mylink">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
```

I want to replace some of this images/links by an iframe(the iframe contain the same things: "mylink" and the image inside), i want something like this:

```html
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 thumb">
                    <iframe id="myiframe" src="iframe-mylink.html"> </iframe>
                </div>
```

I tried a lot of differents things, "embed-responsive" "embed-responsive-4by3", i tried to change height, width, padding, margin, display...

But nothing works, there is always a problem, it's either cropped, too large or too tiny.

What would you suggest me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you tried responsive embed, did you remember to wrap it correctly like this?

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 thumb">
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" id="myiframe" src="iframe-mylink.html"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```